# issue with switch statement c language

Tags: c, switch-statement

So this is the code I'm working on. All is good except that I need to match the case with the counter so I can manage to display the desired output "you are in your tens / teens". I tried many different approaches but I couldn't get it right. However, I think the problem is within the condition. Any tips? Note: I'm just a beginner who just started programming in C this semester!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int YoB, CY, Age;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    printf("Please enter your year of birth");
    scanf_s("%d", &YoB);
    printf("Please enter the current year");
    scanf_s("%d", &CY);
    Age = CY - YoB;
    printf("Entered year of birth %d\n", YoB);
    printf("Entered current year %d\n", CY);
    printf("You are %d years old\n \n", Age);
    if (Age > 18) {
        puts("You are an adult\n");
        if (Age < 18)
            puts("You are a minor\n");
    }
    if(Age<=100){
        while (++counter <= 10);
    }
    switch (counter) {
    case 0:
        puts("You are less than 10\n");
        break;
    case 1:
        puts("you are in your tens / teens\n");
        break;
    case 2:
        puts("You are in your twenties\n");
        break;
    case 3:
        puts("You are in your thirties\n");
        break;
    case 4:
        puts("You are in your fourties\n");
        break;
    case 5:
        puts("You are in your fifties\n");
        break;
    case 6:
        puts("You are in your sixties\n");
        break;
    case 7:
        puts("You are in your seventies\n");
        break;
    case 8:
        puts("You are in your eighties\n");
        break;
    case 9:
        puts("You are in your nineties\n");
        break;
    case 10:
        puts("You are a 100+!!\n");
        break;
    default:
        puts("invalid age!");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code and look at the value of your variables.

Comment: Instead of the loop, how about: `counter = Age / 10;`

Comment: What's the output of the code?

Comment: I'm wondering if the `while (++counter <= 10);` will ever produce any other counter value except `10` ?

Comment: @ItbanSaeed  I think its 11

Comment: @ItbanSaeed, 11?

Comment: BTW, you want: `if (Age >= 18) puts("You are an adult\n"); else puts("You are a minor\n");`

Comment: @Eraklon , Oh yes, it's 11 after terminating the loop :)

Comment: it works with counter=Age / 10; , but i figured if i can do it with a loop and a counter

Comment: If it works with basic division, then why make it more convoluted?

Comment: no actually it will stop executing when the condition is met (to equal 10) so thats the number of iterations the loop will do to match numbers of the cases ex case 0, case 1 etc

Comment: Division is 1 operation.  The loop is many.

Comment: Something like while ((counter++)*10 < Age+10)

Comment: little suggestion: int YoB, CY, Age; can be short unsigned int (age & year has no sign and 2 bytes i think would be sufficient (0 to 65535)). Also think about variable namings and naming convention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer to your problem

You have a simple logic issue in your "counter-setter-loop" (I don't know how I should call this).

```c
if(Age<=100){
     while (++counter <= 10);
}
```

you're incrementing `counter` to `11` not `10`. Suppose `counter` is 10, it'll iterate again, since the condition `<= 10` is still true. As a result you'd need to change this part to:

```c
if(Age<=100){
     while (++counter < 10);
}
```

## Code review

Anyway, when I saw your code, some code improvements went through my head. I hope that's fine for you, if not, you can skip this.

1. adding `\n` to `printf` (little UI improvement)

In my opinion it looks a little bit better, if you create a little prompt and create a new line for the input:

```c
    printf("Please enter your year of birth\n>> ");
    scanf_s("%d", &YoB);

    printf("Please enter the current year\n>> ");
    scanf_s("%d", &CY);
```

2. Logic issue:

There's a logic issue in this part:

```c
    if (Age > 18) {
        puts("You are an adult\n");
        if (Age < 18)
            puts("You are a minor\n");
    }
```

Assuming `Age` is `< 18`. I think that you'd expect to have the output `You are a minor`. But this will never happen because in order to get to the `if (Age < 18)` condition, you'd need to enter the `Age > 18` condition. So I think you mean it like that:

```c
// Also keep in mind that Age can be "< 0" if the user used a "bad" input.
if (Age < 0) {
    puts("You are not born yet.");
} else if (Age >= 18) {
    puts("You are an adult\n");
} else {
    puts("You are a minor\n");
}
```

3. Set `counter` a value instead of using a loop

You can change this part:

```c
    if (Age <= 100){
        while (++counter <= 10);
    }
```

to this:

```c
    if (Age <= 100) {
        counter = 10;
    }
```

although I don't really understand how you can enter the other `case`-arms since `counter` seems to be only `0` or `10` due to the condition above. I think you rather mean something like this:

```c
if (Age <= 100) {
    counter = Age / 10;
}
```

Also please use variable-names which start with a lowercase and not with a uppercase since uppercase Names are rather used for structs, enums or constants etc.

To sum it up, I'd do it as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int birth_year, current_year, age;
    unsigned int tenths = 0;

    printf("Please enter your year of birth\n>> ");
    scanf_s("%d", &birth_year);

    printf("Please enter the current year\n>> ");
    scanf_s("%d", &current_year);

    age = current_year - birth_year;

    printf("Entered year of birth %d\n", birth_year);
    printf("Entered current year %d\n", current_year);
    printf("You are %d years old\n \n", age);

    if (age < 0) {
        puts("You aren't born yet.");
    } else if (age >= 18) {
        puts("You are an adult.\n");
    } else {
        puts("You are a minor.\n");
    }

    if(age <= 100){
        tenths = age % 10;
    }

    switch (tenths) {
        case 0:
            puts("You are less than 10\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            puts("you are in your tens / teens\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            puts("You are in your twenties\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            puts("You are in your thirties\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            puts("You are in your fourties\n");
            break;
        case 5:
            puts("You are in your fifties\n");
            break;
        case 6:
            puts("You are in your sixties\n");
            break;
        case 7:
            puts("You are in your seventies\n");
            break;
        case 8:
            puts("You are in your eighties\n");
            break;
        case 9:
            puts("You are in your nineties\n");
            break;
        case 10:
            puts("You are a 100+!!\n");
            break;
        default:
            puts("invalid age!");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! also a quick note the variable names and all where from an assignment so i only typed what was written. the task i had is to calculate and add a switch statement. anyways, much appreciated

Comment: i think it should be `counter = Age / 10`

Comment: Adulthood is actually `Age >= 18`

Comment: that's correct as well. I'll fix this. Thank you for seeing this!